# PYSPARK_PYTHON setup in jupyter notebooks is ignored

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to setup PYSPARK_PYTHON from a juputer notebook(using jupyter lab) to use a specific conda env but i cannot find a way to make it work, I have found some examples using:

```
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = "<the path>"
```

But it did not work so I also tried:

```
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder \
       .master("yarn-client") \
       .appName(session_name) \
       .config("spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON","<the path>") \
       .enableHiveSupport() \
       .getOrCreate(cluster=cluster)

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

But it never uses the specified python version in the specified path
, question is, is it possible the config is being ignored? do something else needs to be done in notebook?

I'm using yarn-client mode, and i'm using an enterprise/corporate instance of jupyter lab so i cannot set the variables on the cli using export because the server is widely managed for the company by another team so i need to do it with something different than export at cli during jupyter start.

Comment: Can you share how do you connect between Jupyter and PySpark? And how do you start your Jupyter server?

Comment: The connection between jupyter and pyspark is done using the code i posted:
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder \
       .master("yarn-client") \
       .appName(session_name) \
       .config("spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON","<the path>") \
       .enableHiveSupport() \
       .getOrCreate(cluster=cluster)

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

I'm not sure how the jupyter server is started since i use a corporate  server maintained by another team(i'm just an user of it), does the starting method for the server could be affecting?

Comment: It might. One way to test if it has any impact is create a new notebook, selec Spark kernel if needed, the. run a cell eith only `spark` in it. That’s to test of spark session is already initialized when Jupyter kernel is started. Would you mind test it and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help, I ran it and as i suspected i got 
name 'spark' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

To get it working you should also pass those parameters to cli:

```sh
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

Another method is to install findspark package:

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
```

Hope it'll help:
https://www.sicara.ai/blog/2017-05-02-get-started-pyspark-jupyter-notebook-3-minutes

Comment: I cannot run export on cli because i use a corporate jupyter server, i do not start it locally, that's why I need a way to do it from the notebook code.

Comment: It's not an issue, just set it as `os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = "jupyter"` etc.

Comment: Actually you can run any cli command using `!` in jupyter
Ex:
`! pip install findspark`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, but i think you have not understood the issue fully,  the issue is running the conf through os.environ seems to not have effect(it's being ignored), but i cannot use export on cli  or any other cli command because it's a corporate server,
even using ! or magic commands does not work for the same reasons, spark works(so findspark is not useful here) what i need to do is to specify a specific conda environment for running in the worker nodes.